# Does Medal of Honor Warfighter work with WINE?

Tags: wine, games

I can't seem to find any info about it on the WINE database. The previous game, Medal of Honor 2010 has a gold rating so maybe it will run alright. The lack of info on it is probably due to the poor reception the game got. Anyhow if someone has successfully played this game through WINE please let me know.

Also I've never used Play on Linux but if it works of this game I would be willing to give it a try.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the harm in going ahead and trying it?

Comment: Well it might "harm" my wallet for nothing because I haven't actually bought it yet. I probably should have mentioned that.